# copying contents between two csv files django

Tags: python, django, csv

I was trying to copy the contents of `csvfile` into `csvfile2`. I cant see any help on this subject.and I also want to append a value `value` to the first row of `csvfile2`.Eg : `value = 1`
output should be like

```
`1_dog 1_cat 1_frog `
```

when `value=2` result should be

```
2_dog 2_cat 2_frog
```

The value ranges between 1 and the total no of lines in csv file.(`totalrows`)

My trial code:

```
def csvupload(request, template_name='upload_csv.html'):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CSVUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        error_list = set()
        value = 1
        csvfile = request.FILES['file']
        file_name = csvfile.name
        file_name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', file_name).encode('ascii','ignore')
        csvfile2 = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/new/sample.csv'
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, dialect='excel')
        csvfile.open()
        line_entries = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        try:
            csvfile.read()
            line_entries = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
            rows1 = list(csvfile)
            totalrows = len(rows1)
            success = True
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Could not parse file, invalid format")
            success = False
            return redirect('home')


        if success:
            messages.success(request, "File read..")
        else:
            for err in error_list:
                messages.error(request, err)
    else:
        messages.error(request, "No file selected")
else:
    form = CSVUploadForm()
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render_to_response(template_name, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This code is not complete.I am a new to python and confused.Can someone help?

Comment: `1_dog 1_cat 1_frog` does not appear to be csv. Can you show us a couple of lines?

Comment: what I meant  is if the data on the csv file is like dog,cat,frog.. then the new csv file should show the values like 1_dog

Comment: Looks like you have issues with how to open files and how to use the `csv` module. First make your code work outside django, then you might have a chance to make it work inside django...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a python interpreter handy so I cannot test. I can provide more complete answer later.

You need something like this -

To Read -

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

To Write -

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

So, first, save the file in a temporary location in server -

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f): # method to save to a temporary location
    with open('some/file/name.csv', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Then load it and read line by line as above as mentioned in the docs. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

So your code might be something like -

```
def csvupload(request, template_name='upload_csv.html'):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CSVUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        error_list = set()
        value = 1
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file']) # save the file

        file_name = csvfile.name
        file_name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', file_name).encode('ascii','ignore')
        csvfile2 = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/new/sample.csv'
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        row_number = 0
        try:
            with open(csvfile2, 'w') as writtenFile:
                fieldnames = ... # use some code to determine the column names dynamically, may be read the first row and then populate the field names
                writer = csv.DictWriter(writtenFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                    writer.writerow({...})  # write header row
                with open('some/file/name.csv') as csvfile:
                    line_entries = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                    for row in line_entries:
                        row_number = row_number + 1
                        valueDict = [...] # populate the rows as a dict
                        writer.writerow(valueDict);
            success = True
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Could load file, invalid format")
            success = False
            return redirect('home')


        if success:
            messages.success(request, "File read..")
        else:
            for err in error_list:
                messages.error(request, err)
    else:
        messages.error(request, "No file selected")
else:
    form = CSVUploadForm()
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render_to_response(template_name, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```